# Apache Spark Task Ordering

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I was wondering if in Spark's task execution (Scala) it is forced to wait for a previous task to finish before proceeding with the next. I am observing some behaviour in which multiple join statements running in succession are producing inconsistent results.

If it doesn't wait is there a way to force it?

Thanks

Comment: a) [tag:apache] should be used for Apache Server. b) what do you mean by _the next task_? c) could you explain inconsistencies you see? Possibly with [mcve]. It would be easier to put it in some context.

Comment: Thanks for responding I have essentially got a situation in which I generate two RDD's and I am running a join on them. When I run this on a single node on the cluster it returns x num of results and when I run it on say 20 nodes I get y num of results. Sorry I don't have a code example it's not that easy to transfer off the cluster.

Comment: Short answer is -  it doesn't matter. Obviously dependencies have to be generated before given task can be computed but otherwise it can happen in any other. Single task can be even computed multiple times. If you see inconsistent results it is most likely invalid logic, less likely some strange bug. But without reproducible example there is really nothing to do here.

Comment: Sorry I haven't code a more detailed code example I just can't reproduce it out of the context of my code. I have ascertained that the error is being caused by running a join over the results of a ZipWithUniqueID so I'm assuming that is causing some form of issues somewhere.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. `ZipWithUniqueID` should be considered non-deterministic in typical scenarios. It depends on data distribution and this may easily change based on different factors. If you use `DataFrames` (`monotonically-increasing-id) it is even more unpredictable.